# How can I map my Gmail contacts' physical location in Google Maps?

Tags: gmail, google, google-maps

Is there a way plot groups of my Gmail contacts' physical locations in Google Maps?

OS is Windows Vista.

Comment: For some reason I see that as being an invasion of privacy. If such a thing exists, both parties will have to consent to it.

Comment: Static locations such as addresses? Or do you need them to update based on GPS? Have you tried [Google Latitude](http://www.google.com/latitude/)?

Answer (score 2):

Umm, [Google Latitude](https://www.google.com/latitude/)? But of course it needs the contacts to have a mobile device with GPS and their permission.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to sync a Contact Group with a custom Google Map seems like such an obvious feature or easy add-on to program, that I'm amazed it hasn't been done.

There's a workaround that is annoying, but it works and after set-up requires manual maintenance. It uses Google Map's KML import feature. KML is an XML based format for listing mappable addresses and map coordinates.

Steps:

1. Get the KML structure used by Google Maps

   - create a custom map
   - add a few addresses
   - edit to a format that you like
   - export as KML file
2. Export the Contacts Group that you want to map in Outlook .csv format, which is the best format to use with Excel.
3. Build the KML file - It's pretty easy to automate using Excel concatenation. Just keep in mind that XML tags are usually on separate lines for readability, but they can be kept on one line. The master tag for each record is `<Placemark>`, so each line should start and end with `<Placemark>`...`</Placemark>`.
4. Import into new Google Map.

This is a good way to first set-up the map. If you have very frequent changes, you can import more KML files, but infreequent changes are more easily accomplished by directly editing a map.

Now only if someone would step-up and create a sync utility! sigh

Comment: Actually, Google did it! I think you will still need to perform step 2 (export and reimport contacts) but the rest is accomplished automatically via Spreadsheet Mapper: http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/spreadsheet3.html

Answer (score 0):

You Can add GPS location (Lang,Long) to the contacts with Name Maps, So when you click it the maps will take you to the location

Comment: Could you be more specific? How does one create "Name Maps"?

Answer (score -2):

The app has just been created and is in Beta called [INSET](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quad.inset).  Goto Google Play store, download and check out.   The beta will only load 10 contacts. The pro version will allow you to load all your contacts from whatever gmail account you link up with on your browser.